# How can i run scripts using brownie

Tags: python, brownie

I am trying to run my script using brownie but I am getting a constant error  and I searched everywhere I didn't get the answer :

```
def main():
    print("hello bruh")
```

I need to run my codes using  `brownie run scripts/deploy.py`

the error :

```
Successfully installed docopt-0.6.2
PS C:\Users\brosky\Desktop\solidity\Blockchain-development\brownie_simple_storage> brownie run scripts/deploy.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

  File "C:\Users\brosky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", line 64, in main
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\brosky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 36, in main
    args = docopt(__doc__, more_magic=True)
  File "C:\Users\brosky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\brownie\utils\docopt.py", line 814, in docopt
    assert instr.opname.startswith("CALL_")
Assertion error:
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error with Python 3.11. See [this link](https://github.com/jazzband/docopt-ng/issues/49) for further details.